# Http-Server Command Not Found After Install in NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, httpserver

i installed http-server with npm globally but still I get "command not found"

what is wrong

my npm command is that

```
npm install -g http-server
```

and http run command

```
http-server -p 8000
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? Try restarting the terminal.

Comment: Windows 8.1, I restarted computer, and run command panel as administrator
Edit :
Also
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\  in the folder http-server.cmd exists

Answer (score 15, accepted):

as for me, this problem about the PATH. because the sh can't find the script in specifed PATHS.

you should add the npm global script path to your PATH variable.

if you are using "Git Bash", run the below command.

```
PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/CHANGE_WITH_YOUR_USERNAME/AppData/Roaming/npm
```

notice that, this is temporary. when you close the git bash, the PATH variable will be deleted.

for the permanently, you have to create a .bashrc file in your home folder.

run these commands on your git bash.

```
cd ~
echo PATH=\$PATH:/c/Users/CHANGE_WITH_YOUR_USERNAME/AppData/Roaming/npm >> .bashrc
```

Answer (score 3):

Enter the following command in your console

```
sudo npm install http-server -g
```

Answer (score 2):

**@alioygur : Is Exactly Right about the solution.**

But a simple the issue is the installed npm plugin path is not added in the **SYSTEM ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE PATH**. you had to do that manually.

now the question comes what is the path address to put in?

ANSWER : The path of the installed npm plugin generally goes inside the nodejs installation folder >> `nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin`

OR

Sometimes npm plugin also resides inside the temporary APP DATA.(As said by @alioygur)

```
C:\Users\*USERNAME*\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

QUESTION : How to add path to the **SYSTEM ENVIRONMENT** manually without complexity.

ANSWER : http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

Close all cmd and open the cmd and start http-server

Answer (score -2):

Try this **http-server / 8000** if you dont have any specified path

or your problem may be

Port 8000 is the default Remote Method Invocation (RMI) Registry
  port used by the Diagnostic Service.Try Using other port .

Comment: sorry, nothing of them