# Node http server - http: command not found

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I get the error mentioned above in the title, after installing http server on my OSX with

```
npm install http-server -g
```

It installed it in

```
/usr/local/bin/http-server -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
/usr/local/bin/hs -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
/usr/local/lib
```

I tried adding a path since I saw that as a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694646/http-server-command-not-found-after-install-in-npm) like this

```
 PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/http-server
```

Comment: I have run the wrong command instead of http-server I entered http server

Comment: @Marco did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are on linux environment. Try This command to export path

> export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/

Then run your app.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X / linux(ubuntu 16.04) environment. I solved this problem by using follow command

`sudo npm -g install http-server`

`sudo npm install -g http-server`