# GitBash installed but not able to find any node module

Tags: node.js, git, windows-10

I have installed git-bash in windows 10. After that, I installed http-server and lerna globally using -g. When I try to hit http-server or lerna using git bash, it says "command not found". If I try with cmd prompt, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is about the PATH variable. you should add the npm global script path to your PATH variable.

Your question probably has the right answer in the below link.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694646/http-server-command-not-found-after-install-in-npm#:~:text=you%20should%20add%20the%20npm,%22%2C%20run%20the%20below%20command.&text=bashrc%20file%20in%20your%20home,commands%20on%20your%20git%20bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694646/http-server-command-not-found-after-install-in-npm#:%7E:text=you%20should%20add%20the%20npm,%22%2C%20run%20the%20below%20command.&text=bashrc%20file%20in%20your%20home,commands%20on%20your%20git%20bash).